# thread receiving a value and a returning a value

Tags: android, multithreading

i want a method in which a thread is doing process on the value received by the method.After the process in run method it should store the value so that it can be returned by the method

Comment: This is the producer/consumer problem. Usually the threads communicate via a synchronized Queue. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: Can you explain your question properly....

Answer (score 2):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of `Thread`. Here is a good tutorial for this: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/